# Filtering a nested array with objects by checking another nested array with object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, filter

I have an array like this:

```
const state = {
  products: [
    { name: "Potato", amount: "3"},
    { name: "Butter", amount: "1000" },
    { name: "Salt", amount: "2000" },
    //{name: "Egg", amount: "10"},
    { name: "Tomato",  amount: "5"},
    { name: "Sour Milk", amount: "5"}
  ],

  recipes: [
    {
      name: "Mashed potatoes",
      ingredients: [
        { name: "Potato", amount: "5"},
        { name: "Butter", amount: "30"},
        { name: "Salt", amount: "15"}
      ],
      instructions: "Some Text"
    },
    {
      name: "Tomato Omelette",
      ingredients: [
        { name: "Tomato", amount: "1" },
        { name: "Egg", amount: "1" },
        { name: "Salt", amount: "10" },
        { name: "Butter", amount: "40" }
      ],
      instructions: "Some text"
    }
  ]
};
```

I want to filter my recipes array by recipes that I can cook with my products *(in this case I can't cook "Tomato omelette" because I don't have any eggs and I can't cook "Mashed Potatoes" because I don't have enough potatoes)*.

So far I tried different approaches but I didn't come up with a whole solution.

My closest solution was this:

```
const filterRecipes = (filter, products, recipes) => {

  if(filter === 'available products') {
      //Getting all product names for future tests
      const productsNames = products.map(item => item.name);

      //Here we will filter all our recipes by available products 
      const result = recipes.filter(recipe => {
          //Getting all ingredient names of the current recipe
          const ingredientNames = recipe.ingredients.map(item => item.name);

          //If we have all products for our recipe
          //we will add it to our filtered array
          if (ingredientNames.every((name) => productsNames.includes(name))){
              return true;
          }
      })

      console.log(result);
  }
};
```

This one works only for the names of the products but not for its amount. When I'm trying to check for the amount it just brokes.

Here is the whole code:

```js
const state = {
  products: [
    { name: "Potato", amount: "5"},
    { name: "Butter", amount: "1000" },
    { name: "Salt", amount: "2000" },
    //{name: "Egg", amount: "10"},
    { name: "Tomato",  amount: "5"},
    { name: "Sour Milk", amount: "5"}
  ],
  recipes: [
    {
      name: "Mashed potatoes",
      ingredients: [
        { name: "Potato", amount: "5"},
        { name: "Butter", amount: "30"},
        { name: "Salt", amount: "15"}
      ],
      instructions: "Some Text"
    },
    {
      name: "Tomato Omelette",
      ingredients: [
        { name: "Tomato", amount: "1" },
        { name: "Egg", amount: "1" },
        { name: "Salt", amount: "10" },
        { name: "Butter", amount: "40" }
      ],
      instructions: "Some text"
    }
  ]
};

const filterRecipes = (filter, products, recipes) => {

  if(filter === 'available products') {
      //Getting all product names for future tests
      const productsNames = products.map(item => item.name);

      //Here we will filter all our recipes by available products 
      const result = recipes.filter(recipe => {
          //Getting all ingredient names of the current recipe
          const ingredientNames = recipe.ingredients.map(item => item.name);
        
          //If we have all products for our recipe
          //we will add it to our filtered array
          if (ingredientNames.every((name) => productsNames.includes(name))){
              return true;
          }
      })

      console.log(result);
  }
};

filterRecipes("available products", state.products, state.recipes);
```

Comment: What if, say you have ```20``` units of salt and after cooking "Mashed potatoes" there left only 5 units of salt. But for "Tomato Omelette" you need 10 units of salt. What would be the output of this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it like this:

- Set up a `productsObj` with reduce to allow fast lookups
- filter the recipes array
- inside each callback of the recipes filter function, and loop over ingredients of each recipe
- for each ingredient, check it exists in `productsObj` and the amount is larger than or equal to the item in the recipe ingredients.
- if it is present and with large enough qty keep checking the rest of the ingredients
- if not, return false - i.e. filter out of array.

```js
const state = {
  products: [
    { name: "Potato", amount: "5" },
    { name: "Butter", amount: "1000" },
    { name: "Salt", amount: "2000" },
    { name: "Egg", amount: "10" },
    { name: "Tomato", amount: "5" },
    { name: "Sour Milk", amount: "5" }
  ],
  recipes: [
    {
      name: "Mashed potatoes",
      ingredients: [
        { name: "Potato", amount: "5" },
        { name: "Butter", amount: "30" },
        { name: "Salt", amount: "15" }
      ],
      instructions: "Some Text"
    },
    {
      name: "Tomato Omelette",
      ingredients: [
        { name: "Tomato", amount: "1" },
        { name: "Egg", amount: "1" },
        { name: "Salt", amount: "10" },
        { name: "Butter", amount: "40" }
      ],
      instructions: "Some text"
    }
  ]
};

const filterRecipes = (filter, products, recipes) => {
  if (filter === "available products") {
    //Getting all product names in an object for fast look-up
    const productsObj = products.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
      aggObj[item.name] = item;
      return aggObj;
    }, {});
    //console.log("o", productsObj);

    //Here we will filter all our recipes by available products
    const result = recipes.filter((recipe) => {
      let valid = true; //true until proven false

      //Loop over ingredients of each recipe
      for (let i = 0; i < recipe.ingredients.length; i++) {
        const item = recipe.ingredients[i];
        const lookup = productsObj[item.name] || false;
        const quantityEnough = lookup
          ? parseInt(lookup.amount) >= parseInt(item.amount)
          : false;
        if (!quantityEnough) {
          valid = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      return valid;
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
};

filterRecipes("available products", state.products, state.recipes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For example if you change your product quantitiess to:

```js
const state = {
  products: [
    { name: "Potato", amount: "4" },
    { name: "Butter", amount: "1000" },
    { name: "Salt", amount: "2" },
    { name: "Egg", amount: "10" },
    { name: "Tomato", amount: "5" },
    { name: "Sour Milk", amount: "5" }
  ],
```

You get no results as salt and potatoes quantities are not large enough for either recipe.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for faster access, with `amount` as numbers for better comparability

```
{
    Potato: 5,
    Butter: 1000,
    Salt: 2000,
    Tomato: 5,
    "Sour Milk": 5
}
```

and loop only products and recieps once.

This approach uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), where properties are taken out of objects.

The it uses the value of the object and checks the available amount for all ingredients.

```js
const
    filter = ({ products, recipes }) => {
        const avalilable = products.reduce((r, { name, amount }) => (r[name] = +amount, r), {});
console.log(avalilable )
        return recipes.filter(({ ingredients }) =>
            ingredients.every(({ name, amount }) => avalilable[name] >= +amount));
    },
    state = { products: [{ name: "Potato", amount: "5" }, { name: "Butter", amount: "1000" }, { name: "Salt", amount: "2000" }, { name: "Tomato", amount: "5" }, { name: "Sour Milk", amount: "5" }], recipes: [{ name: "Mashed potatoes", ingredients: [{ name: "Potato", amount: "5" }, { name: "Butter", amount: "30" }, { name: "Salt", amount: "15" }], instructions: "Some Text" }, { name: "Tomato Omelette", ingredients: [{ name: "Tomato", amount: "1" }, { name: "Egg", amount: "1" }, { name: "Salt", amount: "10" }, { name: "Butter", amount: "40" }], instructions: "Some text" }] },
    recipes = filter(state);

console.log(recipes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution.

> *Here I add a solution to a situation say, you have `20` units of **"salt"** and the first recipe takes `15` units of them for cooking.*
>
> *Now assume, the second recipe needs `10` units of salt but you have `5` units left at your store. In this situation, you cannot take the
>   second recipe for cooking.*

```js
const state = {
  products: [
    { name: "Potato", amount: "5"},
    { name: "Butter", amount: "1000" },
    { name: "Salt", amount: "20" },
    { name: "Egg", amount: "1"},
    { name: "Tomato",  amount: "5"},
    { name: "Sour Milk", amount: "5"}
  ],
  recipes: [
    {
      name: "Mashed potatoes",
      ingredients: [
        { name: "Potato", amount: "5"},
        { name: "Butter", amount: "30"},
        { name: "Salt", amount: "15"}
      ],
      instructions: "Some Text"
    },
    {
      name: "Tomato Omelette",
      ingredients: [
        { name: "Tomato", amount: "1" },
        { name: "Egg", amount: "1" },
        { name: "Salt", amount: "10" },
        { name: "Butter", amount: "40" }
      ],
      instructions: "Some text"
    }
  ]
};


const filterRecipes = (filter, products, recipes) => {
 if (filter === 'available products') {
  
  /**
  * Restructure the products from array to object.
  * like {Potato: "20", "Salt": "200"}
  */
  const store = products.reduce((a, {name, amount}) => {
   return {...a, [name]: amount};
  }, {});
  
  
  const canCook = recipes.filter(recipe => {
   /**
      * Convert ingredient from array to object like products
      *
      */
   const ingredients = recipe.ingredients.reduce((a, {name, amount}) => {
    return {...a, [name]: amount};
   }, {});
   
   /**
   * Check if every ingredients are available at the store
   */
   const allow = Object.entries(ingredients).every(([name, amount]) => {
    return (store[name] !== undefined && (+store[name]) >= (+amount));
   });

   /**
   * This is for reducing the amount of ingredient from the store
   * if the recipe is taken for cooking.
   * You can omit it if you don't need to measure this factor.
   */
   if (allow) {
    Object.entries(ingredients).forEach(([name, amount]) => {
     store[name] -= amount;
    });
   }
   
   return allow;
  });
  
  console.log(canCook);
 }
}

filterRecipes("available products", state.products, state.recipes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```